# Magento2: How to get admin details on front side?

Tags: magento2, frontend, customer-account, admin-panel

I have added  login as customer extension.

When I login to customer from admin panel then I want also admin details on front end side. who admin login as customer.

My Magento v2.0.17

Comment: you can use Auth model for the same

Comment: Which will return details of current login user

Comment: When I login as a customer  from admin panel then some data will show only for admin...I want  to admin all details frontend side like id, name, addrss etc. @AdityaShah

Comment: Customer login successfully from admin side...But I can't find Who admin login as a customer at frontend side. So i will show only advanced data to Admin user at frontend. @AdityaShah

Comment: use Magento\Customer\Model\Context as CustomerContext;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session as CustomerSession;

Comment: this will give data

Comment: Can I pass admin details at frontend when login as customer dashboard? @AdityaShah

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84715/discussion-between-aditya-shah-and-masud-shaikh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Back-end**

```
protected $authSession;
public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession, 
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->authSession = $authSession;
    ....
}
```

Get data in method

```
public function getCurrentUser()
{
    return $this->authSession->getUser();
}
```

this will give you the **current logged in admin**.
You can later get the details like `$user->getUsername()` or `$user->getEmail()`

**Front-end**

```
protected $_session;
protected $_context;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
) {     
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->objectManager = $context->getObjectManager();
} 


public function isCustomerLoggedIn()
{
    $session = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');    
    return $session->isLoggedIn();
}

public function getCustomerId(){
    $session = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');    
    return $session->getCustomer()->getId();
}
```

Comment: I will check and update you soon...Thanks

Comment: Hi @AdityaShah Can you check my module?

Comment: Check your module ? How ?